# Writing a bubble sort function that sorts scores numerically, but drags the name string along with it

Tags: c, function, bubble-sort

So I have a project that requires us to store the top 10 high scores in a text file and be able to display them in the terminal. The scores should be paired with the user's name, and when I bubble sort them from highest to lowest the corresponding name should follow along. This is what I have now, which I know is just a normal bubble sort function, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
void bubbleSort(int score[])   
{   
     int var;         

     for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)         
         for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)         
         {             
             if (score[j] > score[j+1])             
             {                 
                 var = score[j];   
                 score[j] = score[j+1];  
                 score[j+1] = var;  
              }        
          }  
 }
```

Comment: If you have an array of names corresponding to the array of scores, simply swap the names in the same indices whenever you swap the scores. (That is, compare scores only but sort both scores and names.)

Comment: Alternatively, use an array of structures where each element contains both the score and the name.